# Firebase real-time data base, add new timestamp child node upon every login?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm very new to firebase as this is my first project so any help is appreciated because this problem has taken quite a few hours of my time. I think the solution could be very simple but I'm failing to see it.

I would like to collect user-specific data upon every login to the app so it'd be something like this (in the real-time database):

```
-user-id{
        -10:40:50:{
                   -location:"loation1",
                   -activity:"walking",
                   -batteryLevel:"90%"
                    }
        -11:50:30:{
                   -location:"location2",
                   -activity:"running",
                   -battery-level:"80%"
                   }
    }
```

I have tried to start by simply making different nodes (the timestamps) for every login before I go into more details with the children of these timestamps (location, activity and battery level).
 I thought the code below would create something like this:

```
-user-id{
        -10:40:50:"10:40:50"
        -11:50:30:"11:50:30"
        }
```

But instead I only get

```
-user-id{
         -11:50:30:"11:50:30"
        }
```

**My problem is that every time the user logs in, the new timestamp overwrites the old one so user-id always has only one child node (the timestamp associated with the latest login).**

This is the code I tried. **PS:** I have tried replacing ".setValue()" with ".push().setValue()" but the last timestamp always erases the previous one.

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
    myRef.setValue( firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
    String currentDateTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    DatabaseReference usersRef = myRef.child(currentDateTime );

    usersRef.setValue(currentDateTime);
```

The code above I've put it in the Oncreate of the activity "ProfileActivity.java" which is basically the activity the user is redirected to after he is correctly authenticated.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very silly mistake.

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
myRef.setValue( firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

These two lines of code always **completely** clear your node and set the value to your `Uid`.

If the node looked like this before

```
user123
    - name:"peter"
    - 10:40:50:"10:40:50"
```

it will now look like this

```
user123:"user123"
```

You set the complete content of the node to your `Uid`. If you just remove your `myRef.setValue(...)` statement, your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's very silly indeed. I kept ocusing on the child and thought the problem was with the second "setValue" (    usersRef.setValue(currentDateTime)) and didn't even check the first one where I'm actually setting the content of the parent node.

Comment: thank you very much, you've saved my a great deal of time.